# Is is possible to provide the path in StorageClass to store the data at that path in K8's?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm using StorageClass and PVC(to claim the resources). AS the StoageClass create the Pesistent-Volume according to the PVC, so the Path used by the PV to store data is default path.

Here is my StorageClass Yaml file:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: elastic-storage-class

provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
parameters:
  path: /mydata/data/elastic-pvc
  type: DirectoryOrCreate
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

Here is my PersistentVolumeClaim Yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elastic-pvc

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: elastic-storage-class
```

After deploying both objects, and when I describe the PV I get the default path which `/tmp/hostpath-provisioner/default/elastic-pvc`.

I want to change the path to `elastic/data/elastic-pvc` , Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the default StorageClass**

You need to create a new storage class for `elastic/data/elastic-pvc`
To check the StorageClass in the cluster run the below command:

```
       kubectl get storageclass
```

If the output shows `elastic/data/elastic-pvc`as default then mark the default StorageClass as non-default.

To mark a StorageClass as non-default, you need to change its value to false in below command

```
kubectl patch Storageclass standard -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"false"}}}'
```

For more information you can refer to the documentation [Change the default StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/#why-change-the-default-storage-class)